# How to add default dd/mm/yyyy label instead of null selector in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Here is code for date selector in my rails form-

```
  <div class="field columns large-3">
    <%= form.label :planned_start_date, :class=>"required" %>
    <%= form.date_select :planned_start_date, start_year: @project_start_year, end_year: @project_end_year, :include_blank => true, order: [:day, :month, :year], class: 'select-date' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field columns large-3">
    <%= form.label :planned_end_date, :class=>"required" %>
    <%= form.date_select :planned_end_date, start_year: @project_start_year, end_year: @project_end_year, :include_blank => true, order: [:day, :month, :year], class: 'select-date' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add dd mm yyyy instead of null selector by default. How can i change that?

Comment: you can use `prompt` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in ruby doc for [date_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select)

```
= form.date_select :planned_end_date, start_year: @project_start_year, end_year: @project_end_year, :include_blank => true, order: [:day, :month, :year], prompt: { day: 'dd', month: 'mm', year: 'yyyy' }, class: 'select-date'
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.. ```:include_blank => true``` this is not required